# How do I change my dreamweaver template to hold the Navigation title when a HTML file is created?

Tags: html, templates, dreamweaver

The problem that I am having is that when I change the title in the HTML file, it changes when the template file is modified.

Here is the top part of my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="title" -->
<title></title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
```

Here is what it gives me in the HTML files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/ungr_template.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="title" -->
Layout 1 -
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

So I changed it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/ungr_template.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="title" -->
<title>Undergraduate Research Opportunities</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

But whenever I make a change to the Template it goes back to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/ungr_template.dwt" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<head>
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="title" -->
Layout 1 
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

Comment: @Tim B James That's not constructive.

Comment: @SinthiaV maybe not, but true. Dreamweaver, from when i used to use it years and years ago, was always adding in extra code, changing code, and doing things which i never wanted to happen. So i stopped using it in favour of coding html and css myself. As a result i know how to build websites without relying on a "tool" to do it. Also, if you are wanting to use software to help with the development of websites, then there are much better options out there. Web Matrix fr example.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="title" -->
Layout 1 
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```

to

```
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Layout 1</title>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
```